# How do I return only image src from "woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail()"?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails, hook-woocommerce

```
echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
```

That output the whole image tag.
How can I get only the image source?

Same problems solution with just WordPress:
[How do I get image url only on the_post_thumbnail](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/how-do-i-get-image-url-only-on-the-post-thumbnail)

Is that possible with WooCommerce?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to write your own code based on the function `woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail()` from  `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php`. For example:

```php
function my_get_the_product_thumbnail_url( $size = 'shop_catalog' ) {
  global $post;
  $image_size = apply_filters( 'single_product_archive_thumbnail_size', $size );
  return get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, $image_size );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the thumbnail of any post as such:

`$thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID);`

Answer (score 2):

it also provides the image URL through normal WordPress get post URL method
try this:

```
<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought woocommerce post thumbnail is different than normal post thumbnail( self teaching limits) . But they are the same thing.

So to get just the "src" attribute aka image url use the following line-

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( $size ); ?>
```